# format date from 14 aug to YYYYMMDD

Tags: java, date, format

Change the date 14 aug 2011 to the format 20110814 .. how can i do that in java ?

Here 14aug is a string ... String date="14aug";

Comment: Is `14 aug 2011` a date string or date object?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
String yyyyMMdd = sdf.format(date);
```

Reference: [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Update: the question by The Elite Gentleman is important. If you start with a `String`, then you should first parse it to obtain the `date` object from the above example:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy").parse(dateString);
```

Comment: the example would not have threading issue. If you decide to have the formatter as an instance field, rather than a local variable, then be careful with thread-safety. You can use a ThreadLocal (common-practice)

Comment: @Michał Niklas that is true, but it isn't a part of the requirement (or at least I don't know if it is) :)

Answer (score 6):

The other answers were good answers in 2011 when they were written. Time moves on. Today no one should use the now long outdated classes `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. The modern answer uses the `java.time` classes:

```
    String date = "14 aug 2011";
    DateTimeFormatter parseFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .appendPattern("dd MMM uuuu")
            .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
    System.out.println(LocalDate.parse(date, parseFormatter)
                        .format(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE));
```

This prints the desired:

```
20110814
```

The modern parsing mechanism is somewhat stricter because experience shows that the old one was way too lenient and often produced surprising results in situations where one would have expected an error message. For example, the modern one requires correct case, that is, capital A in Aug in English, **unless** we tell it that it should parse without case sensitivity. So this is what I am doing with the `parseCaseInsensitive()`. The call affects the *following* builder method calls, so we have to place it *before* `appendPattern()`.

Edit: Taking your string `"14aug"` from the question literally. `SimpleDateFormat` would have used 1970 as default year (year of the epoch), giving you trouble how to get the correct year. The modern classes allow you to specify a default year explicitly, for example:

```
    String date = "14aug";
    DateTimeFormatter parseFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .appendPattern("ddMMM")
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR, Year.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).getValue())
            .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

With this change, running the code today we get:

```
20170814
```

Edit 2: Now using `DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE` for formatting as recommended in [Basil Bourque’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44462771/5772882).

Answer (score 1):

While example given by Bozho is good for English locale it may not work in other locales (as long as *"aug"* is not month name in other locale). For my environment with Polish locales I would rather use something like:

```
ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse("14 aug 2011", pos);
```

Also note usage of `ParsePosition` which in case of parse problems (then `date` will be `null`) will tell you at what position parsing had troubles.

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44456547/642706) is excellent. It shows you the modern approach using java.time classes rather than the troublesome old legacy date-time classes ( `Date` & `Calendar` ).

## `MonthDay`

I will extend that Answer by adding one thought: You can represent your input of day-of-month number and abbreviated Month name as a [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html) object.

To understand the use of `DayeTimeFormatterBuilder` here, see that other [Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44456547/642706).

```
String input = "11aug" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = 
    new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()  
        .parseCaseInsensitive()
        .appendPattern( "ddMMM" )
        .toFormatter( Locale.ENGLISH )
;
MonthDay md = MonthDay.parse( input , f ) ;
```

> md.toString(): --08-11

If possible, I suggest using the ISO 8601 standard format `--MM-DD` for textually representing a month-day value, rather than your own custom non-standard format. The java.time classes including `MonthDay` use the standard formats by default when parsing and generating strings, so no need to specify a formatting pattern. To parse: `MonthDay md = MonthDay.parse( "--08-11" ) ;`.

Generate a date-only value by specifying your desired year. Specifically, a `LocalDate` object.

```
LocalDate ld = md.atYear( 2011 ) ;
```

> ld.toString(): 2011-08-11

Your desired output format happens to comply with the standard ISO 8601 formats. Your format is the “Basic” version that minimizes the use of separators. This format is already defined in [`DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#BASIC_ISO_DATE).

```
String output = ld.format( DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE ) ;
```

> 20110811

Comment: Certainly a good option. I think I prefer it over my own.One reason is this one lends itself better to selecting a year depending on the date. For just one example, there could be a requirement that the date be within the next 6 months from now; much easier to validate and calculate the correct year from a `MonthDay`.

Comment: @OleV.V. My Answer is an extension of yours rather than an alternative. You gave a nice explanation and example of using a formatter-builder for parsing the non-standard input.