# Date format in java

Tags: java, date, format

```
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMM", Locale.ENGLISH);

      try {

        sdf.parse(sDate);
      } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

My date format is 04AUG2011 and i want to have 20110804. So how can i do that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [format date from 14 aug to YYYYMMDD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220061/format-date-from-14-aug-to-yyyymmdd)

Comment: You've asked this **exact** question before.

Comment: yes but i tried that and i got a new error ...

Comment: These days (2017 an on) I recommend you discard the outdated `SimpleDateFormat` and friends and use the classes in the `java.time` package (from 2014). For how to, see [my answer to the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44456547/5772882).

Answer (score 2):

Use the following format:

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

I think you need to differentiate between parsing and outputting:

```
 SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMdd", Locale.ENGLISH);
 SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd", Locale.ENGLISH);
 String dateStr = "06Sep";
 // parse with 06Sep format
 Date din = parseFormat.parse(dateStr);
 // output with 20101106 format
 System.out.println(String.format("Output: %s", outputFormat.format(din)));
```

Comment: But i got this ERROR .. Unparseable date: "06Sep"

Comment: @Praneel, that wasn't the example you posted. Read the javadocs for other formats!

Comment: You need to differentiate between parsing and outputting. If your date is ni "06Sep" format, you need new `SimpleDateFormat("ddMMM")`

Answer (score 0):

Change your dateformat to

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: -1: won't work since "mm" will output minutes not month value.

Comment: sorry, thought i had the shift key pressed, Edited now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete working sample. I hope next time, you will do your own work.

```
/**
 * 
 */

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;


/**
 * @author The Elite Gentleman
 *
 */
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            String date = "06Sep2011";
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
            Date d = sdf.parse(date);

            SimpleDateFormat nsdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd", Locale.ENGLISH);
            String nd = nsdf.format(d);
            System.out.println(nd);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```