# Date format with Java

Tags: java, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [format date from 14 aug to YYYYMMDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220061/format-date-from-14-aug-to-yyyymmdd)

Hi I need to get a date in a YYYYMMDD format. I Don't know the right method for that...
I set the date with this lines of code...

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    cal.clear();

    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    cal.set(Calendar.DATE, date);
```

Later in the code I need to extract the YYYYMMDD date value, how I can do that?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/CatalogData-Type.htm

Comment: Lol same answer 3 times in 34 seconds I think you have it there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
format.setCalendar(cal);
String text = format.format(cal.getTime());
```

Personally I would *strongly* recommend that you look at using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead though - it's a much nicer API than the built-in `Date`/`Calendar` class.

Comment: Thanks for the plug (Joda Time)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `SimpleDateFormat` class.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMMDD");
String date = sdf.format(new Date());
```

The above code should give you the current date in the format `YYYYMMDD`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look to the API documentation for SimpleDateFormat class. It provides a format method.

Comment: new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(cal.getTime()) or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

[SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)
It's great for problems like this

Answer (score 0):

According to the Calendar [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), you should use the DateFormat class. The documentation for DateFormat can be found [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html)

If these do not suit your needs, then you can make a custom wrapper class for Calendar and override the `toString()` method